# Transaction delayed >12 hours by Satoshi Bitcoin client

Tags: transactions, client, bitcoind, bitcoin-core, linux

Yesterday I sent 20 BTC to [1Hj8kJ3rq4c4Hn9Prtw45Zue791f4Nc9L3](http://blockchain.info/tx-index/48227440/30d1ef9aa05898b11b5ee4f5f5e703a822a821fb499c647b658fc3cb67a899b8) with a 0.0001 fee and transaction Id [30d1ef9aa05898b11b5ee4f5f5e703a822a821fb499c647b658fc3cb67a899b8](http://blockchain.info/tx-index/48227440/30d1ef9aa05898b11b5ee4f5f5e703a822a821fb499c647b658fc3cb67a899b8).

My Satoshi client said today that is still unconfirmed. But when I search blockchain.info for the id of the transaction, it says that the transaction was sent today (>12 hours after I made it).

Is there any way, if a transaction isn't relayed, to force the satoshi client to send it another time (the same transaction).

Answer (score 1):

That transacation has over 1,400 confirmations. I think you might need to run your client with the rescan option on. (That rescans the blockchain for transactions it might have missed)

Answer (score 0):

It may happen that the transaction is not sent to the network immediately. When creating a new transaction the client will announce its availability to its peers and they will fetch it. If in the meantime you turn your client off, it crashes or you lose connection to the peers, they will not be able to retrieve and broadcast it through the network.

No worry through as your client attempts to resend unconfirmed transactions at regular intervals.

To force a resend you can use [getrawtransaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions#getrawtransaction_.3Ctxid.3E_.5Bverbose.3D0.5D) and [sendrawtransaction](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Raw_Transactions#sendrawtransaction_.3Chex_string.3E) of the JSON-API. That worked for me a few times.

Comment: Don't suggest using raw transactions, it is dangerous to do so!

Comment: cdecker's suggested use of the raw transaction api is very safe. Creating raw transactions yourself is where you need to be very careful.